# Accessing file size information in IE and JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The code given below work fine with firefox but not not with ie....

```
<script language="javascript">
function findSize() {
    var fileInput =  document.getElementById("filename");

    f_size=fileInput.files[0].size; // Size returned in bytes.
    if(f_size>=2000000)
    {
        alert("File Should be less than or equel to 2MB");
        return false;
    }
    return true;   
}
```

give any solution

Comment: IE doesn't support the `.files` collection, nothing you can do about it

Comment: Try to look for errors in your console...

Comment: use firebug, and see what errors show up

Comment: @AmitApollo Firebug in IE. Fantastic. It's not like IE has had fully-functional Developer Tools since IE8.

Comment: @Niet, "Fully-functional"... HAHAHAHA, best laugh I've had this morning - it's awful, and every time I've tried to us it I've ended up killing the IE process.

Comment: Firebug in firefox to check for errors. I'm almost certain the reason it's not working however is .getElementById("filename"). IE is very touchy about naming conventions of classes and ID's. With hashtags or sans the hashtag in the naming convention.

Comment: @Amit, the OP has already stated it works in FireFox, and that is because FireFox supports the `.files` collection - using FireBug in a browser that supports the collection is not going to help work out why it's failing in IE

Comment: Sometimes it runs fine in Firefox, yet errors show up in the logs regardless. I've had scripts that work fine in Chrome and Firefox, yet when you look at the console, you'll see errors, it never hurts to look, despite the lack of "visible" errors

Comment: Clearly I am surrounded by people who are just fine with dismissing a large number of their users. That's fine. I'll just let you know that, having been using IE as my primary browser for many years, I have *never* encountered any of the seemingly unending list of faults people have with it. Maybe I'm just lucky, or maybe I just know how to use it -shrugs-

Comment: @Neit - very, very, very lucky... as a web developer with quite a number of years under my commercial belt, I regularly see issues with IE... but as somebody who does NOT dimiss IE users (as much as I would like to) I battle through the inconsistencies to make my sites work as well as possible for ALL users. Maybe you should think before being so condescending

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, depending on the IE version you cannot use the latest JavaScript APIs and cannot access that information.

The solution is to stop using IE or parse that information on the server-side. I highly recommend the former.

Please see http://caniuse.com/ for the availability of JavaScript APIs for various browser versions.

Comment: How many web developers do you think have the ability to MAKE their users "stop using IE"??  It would be great, but that's not exactly a helpful statement

Comment: Nice site, but unless I'm being really stupid, where is the information for the `.files` collection?

Comment: maybe add the HTML in the question where you reference the DOM element filename. It'd help to see the surrounding code.

Comment: Info on `HTMLInputElement.files`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList